# yii 1.1.16 настройка при переносе

Tags: yii

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно кроме .htaccess менять, если переносишь сайт? на пример на подддомен. перенес на поддомен, переписал редиректы. загружается, чистая страница ( иконка подтягивается ) и все. Ошибок нет.

Comment: display_errors какое значение в конфиге php имеет?

Comment: 'errorAction' => 'site/error',   Этот же сайт работает на основном домене. при переносе на поддомен. возникли проблемы ( исходный код рабочий ) настройки не правильные

Comment: Я про параметр из php.ini спрашиваю, а вы мне про errorAction отвечаете.

Comment: "log_errors", 1/но я посмотрел в protected  log там изменений нет ( за текущюю дату)

Comment: display_errors в php.ini !

Comment: Проблема в том , что на хостинге, нет доступа к php.ini  , но в htaccess прописано правило php_flag display_errors        off
php_value error_log "/home/c/site/nn/error_log"

Comment: И что в этом логе есть?

Comment: ошибок никаких нет.

Comment: дело в том, удаляю index.php входной файл в коренной директории и htaccess , даже после этого , ошибки нет!

Comment: Возможно, техническая поддержка хостинга давно бы решила проблему. Вы же им деньги платите.

Comment: Проблема было банальна. в директории лежал index.html с 0 размером, который перехватывал запрос